# "Please" or "Sorry" as Sentences

Tags: single-word-requests

Is please, or, sorry, a sentence?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELU.  I have edited your question, but you need to edit it also.  I suggest you read the guidance on asking questions.  You need to explain why you are in doubt about whether you can have a one-word sentence like this and show what efforts you have made to find out for yourself.  For example, have you looked up the word 'sentence' in a couple of dictionaries (for example the on-line versions of Merriam Webster and the Cambridge English) to see if there is a definition that fits?

Comment: What single word are you looking for here? If you’re looking for a word that describes something, you have to tell us what you’re looking for. This doesn’t seem to be a single-word request (and the question you’re actually asking has been asked and answered before).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following text:

> Person A: Sorry. I can't help you.
>
> Person B: Please!

In this dialog the words *sorry* and *please* are considered *orthographical sentences* since they begin with a capital letter and finish with end punctuation (*period/full stop, question mark, exclamation mark*.)

So every string of words starting with a capitalised word and concluding with end punctuation is an orthographical sentence.

But are *Sorry.* and *Please!* grammatical sentences? Based on the traditional notional definition of a sentence as *a complete thought* then the answer must be *yes*. But the concept of *a complete thought* is now considered to be too vague to be useful.

An alternative definition of a grammatical sentence is that it has a subject and a predicate (i.e. it consists of at least one, independent, clause). For example:

> I can't help you (subject: *I*, predicate: *can't help you*).

But even here there is a problem, since the words *Help me!* have no (explicit) subject, yet are considered to be a grammatical sentence.

In summary, there is no simple answer to the question *Is '(string of words)' a sentence*? A good overview of the issue can be found on ThoughtCo:  [Sentence Definition and Examples in English Grammar](https://www.thoughtco.com/sentence-grammar-1692087)